# Eslint rule for preventing direct react state modification

Tags: reactjs, eslint

In my team some developers modify react state directly like this:

```
this.state.something = 123;
```

I've already explained why they must never ever do this again. But now we need to find all these cases and fix. It's quite hard to do manually in a large project.

Is there an eslint rule for detecting such cases?

Comment: This regex might help you find all these errors: ``\(this.state.).+[=].+\``. Just search for that in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-direct-mutation-state.md) rule from [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react)